# I can`t import wxpython in anywhere except python console

Tags: python, wxpython

I installed python 3.8.8 and installed wxpython using pip at terminal

> pip install wxpython

and i run simple program

```
import wx
print(wx.version())
```

in pycharm and pycharm`s python console, I got

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wx'
```

in IDLE, I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tasoo/OneDrive/Desktop/wx.py", line 1, in <module>
    import wx
  File "C:/Users/tasoo/OneDrive/Desktop\wx.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(wx.version())
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'wx' has no attribute 'version' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

in python.exe code works

I want to import wx in pycharm project.
I tried add python in system path but it didn`t work.

Comment: you have problem because you saved code in file `wx.py` and now `import wx` loads your file `wx.py` instead of module `wx`. Rename your file - ie. `main.py` instead of `wx.py`.

Comment: I solved problem in IDLE. However i already saved the code as main.py in pycharm. how can I solve problem in pycharm?

Comment: `PyCharm` may have own Python installed and it may need to install `wx` in this Python. Check `import sys` `print(sys.executable)` to get full path to Python used by PyCharm and then use this path `/full/path/to/python -m pip install wx`. OR search in PyCharm `settings` (probably in menu `File` or `Edit`) and change `Python Interpreter`. In PyCharm for every project you may set different Python (if you have installed many versions)

Answer (score 1):

You have problem because you saved code in file `wx.py` and now `import wx` loads your file `wx.py` instead of module `wx`. Rename your file - ie. `main.py` instead of `wx.py`

---

`PyCharm` may have own Python installed and it may need to install `wx` in this Python.

Check

```
import sys 
print(sys.executable)
```

to get full path to Python used by `PyCharm` and then use this path

```
/full/path/to/python -m pip install wx
```

Or search in `PyCharm settings` (in menu `File`) and change `Python Interpreter`.

In `PyCharm` for every project you may set different Python - if you have installed many versions.